# Formula to remove thousands of stock codes from cells

Tags: google-sheets

I have a long list of 27,000 stock codes that I want to remove from a list of URLs.

I have tried this formula

=REGEXREPLACE(B2,$C$2:$C$27078,"")

To replace the stock codes with nothing but it doesn't remove the stock code. Is the list too long to process it or is my formula wrong?

Sorry I'm a spreadsheet noob.

Comment: Post few sample data.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 0):

**Paste this formula** asuming we have Sheet1, Sheet2

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(B2:B="",,REGEXREPLACE(B2:B,$C$2:$C,"")))
```

**Sheet2**
[image]

**Sheet1**
[image]